# Store data retrieved from Qr code within the app using shared preference

Tags: android, listview

i am working on an app in which i have to store the contact detail retrieved from qr code using shared preference (or any suggestion how i can store the information) within the app and store it in list view in another activity. I am new to Android and any help will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

just used the shared preference and stored the result in arraylist and add them to listview in android.
use listview tutorial and concept of shared preference and make a note on Gson to Json.